# Basic implementation of table-dragger

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement table-dragger(basic), and am unable to understand how to get it done.

Following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>draggable</title>
  <script src="/Desktop/table-dragger.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var el = document.getElementById('table');

  var dragger = tableDragger(el, {
  mode: 'row',
  dragHandler: '.handle',
  onlyBody: true,
  animation: 300
});
dragger.on('drop',function(from, to){
  console(from);
  console(to);
});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table">

    <thead>

    <tr>

      <th class='handle'>Header 1</th>

      <th class='handle'>Header 2</th>

      <th class='handle'>Header 3</th>

    </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td>Cell 1</td>

      <td>Cell 2</td>

      <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have provided the path to the table-dragger.min.js as well.What is to be done here now? The page doesn't display any draggable content(row).

Comment: Perhaps, if there are any links that could help me understand the basics, that would help as well.

Comment: Are you sure `table-dragger.min.js` is being correctly loaded ? I know no system that use `/Desktop` as directory

Comment: I was unaware about the same, I had assumed that the path from my directory needs to be provided here.Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your console, you must see a `JS` error. Something like

```
table-dragger: el must be TABLE HTMLElement, not [object Null]
```

This is because your DOM doesn't have any table added in there when you are trying to get it with

```
 var el = document.getElementById('table');
```

And it gives you null. So you `table-dragger` throws an error.

A quick fix is just move your `sctipt` where `body` tag is being closed and that should fix it.

Something like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>draggable</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-dragger@1.0.2/dist/table-dragger.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<table id="table">

    <thead>

    <tr>

      <th class='handle'>Header 1</th>

      <th class='handle'>Header 2</th>

      <th class='handle'>Header 3</th>

    </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td>Cell 1</td>

      <td>Cell 2</td>

      <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var el = document.getElementById('table');

  var dragger = tableDragger(el, {
  mode: 'row',
  dragHandler: '.handle',
  onlyBody: true,
  animation: 300
});
dragger.on('drop',function(from, to){
  console(from);
  console(to);
});
</script>
</body>

  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move row then change dragHandler: ""

```
var dragger = tableDragger(el,{    
 mode: 'row',
dragHandler: '',
onlyBody: true,
animation: 300
});
```

And put script tag before < /body>